# M2Crypto Error Installing on Windows

Tags: python, m2crypto

I'm trying to install the M2Crypto on Python26 in Windows, but I am getting the below error.

> **error**: command 'swig.exe' failed: No such file or directory

This error occurs both using the "Easy Install" or "PIP Install" command. Follows the Log:

> running build
>
> running build_py
>
> running build_ext
>
> building 'M2Crypto.__m2crypto' extension
>
> swigging SWIG/_m2crypto.i to SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c
>
> swig.exe -python -IC:\Python26\include -IC:\Python26\PC
>   -Ic:\pkg\include -includeall -o SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c SWIG/_m2crypto.i
>
> error: command 'swig.exe' failed: No such file or directory

Any Help?

Comment: @Stephan I edited my question to improve the explanation. Thanks for your attention

Comment: Alternatively you could try to install a binary build from http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto

Comment: @Eduardo Simple answer: Do not use Windows and make your life easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting this in answer format:

You could try to install a binary build from http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto

from mata's comment that resolved OP's issue

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me: (using winpython2.7)

```
pip install M2CryptoWin32
```

reference:
https://github.com/dsoprea/M2CryptoWin32